# How are the three channels of an ISDN line seperated from each other? And how does that differ from the way channesl are divided in a DSL line?

Tags: networking, cable, adsl, wired-networking

- My thinking is (pls correct me if I'm wrong)an ISDN line has two **B
  channels** for data transferring and a **D channel** for signaling;
  channels of a DSL line are separated by frequencies of the electromagnetic waves(eg, 0~4kHz for phone calls).
- So the question
  is **how are channels of an ISDN line separated** from each other?
  And how does that differ from the way channels are separated in a DSL
  line?

Comment: You are talking an old school BRI ISDN circuit? Do you understand that ISDN is a true digital service, meaning that what travels down the line is nothing but logical ones and zeros... Oversimplified, it's 48 bits for B1, then 4 bits of D, then 48 bits for B2, then 4 bits of D, repeated 4000 times per second. All of these questions can be answered quite nicely by Google, start here perhaps: https://slideplayer.com/slide/5109129/ And DSL is a completely different technology entirely, and the answer would actually vary based on which flavor of DSL your referring to, ADSL, VDSL, SDSL, IDSL, etc.